# How to pass multiple arguments to views_embed_view?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a form in .module file. In the form submit button I am embedding my view using views_embed_view function. I want to pass multiple arguments to the view.
Here is my code

`print views_embed_view('testing_signup_info', 'default', '1,2,3');`


The above code works fine and three arguments are passed to the view but i want to get sid from signup_log table and pass them as the arguments to the view.
Here is my code.

`$result = db_query("SELECT sid from signup_log");

$rows = array();

while($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {

$r = $row['sid'];

$rows[$r] = $row['sid'];

drupal_set_message($r);

}

drupal_set_message(views_embed_view('testing_signup_info', 'default', '"' . $rows .'"'));`


but here my view does not display.
I need help if someone know the solution.
How to pass sids retrieving from the table and pass as arguments to the view???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you included appears to pass in an array. Based on my understanding from [this comment by merlinofchaos](http://groups.drupal.org/node/17397#comment-59414) (the author of Views), it doesn't look like Views expects an array to be passed in. Try the following instead:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT sid from signup_log");
$rows = array();
while($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
  $r = $row['sid'];
  $rows[$r] = $row['sid'];
  drupal_set_message($r);
}
$rows_string = implode("+", $rows);
drupal_set_message(views_embed_view('testing_signup_info', 'default', $rows));
```

Comment: p.s. - You may get more answers if you accept some of the answers to your previous questions.